# How to create a Microsoft Office like application in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, ms-office

Occasionally when downloading a free-ware tool they have the same shell/style/looks as Microsoft Office applications. [Edraw for example](https://www.edrawsoft.com/).

I am looking to develop a slimmed down Visio style application in C#, and using a standardized Office-shell could really save me some time.

I figured there must be some tooling or Visual Studio thing to create an application with the Office-shell, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is called, or find some more information about it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? It would be much appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean an application with ribbon menu and an editor?

Comment: If it's a Ribbon you are after, start here: 


 https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I believe the Ribbon is what I am looking for, thanks! Atleast partially anyway. If I go back to the Edraw example, the drawing area (i.e. the ruler, shapelibraries, etc) has so many similarities to Microsoft Visio, but this can't all be the Ribbon, can it?

Comment: If you want to create an Office inspired App that mimic the whole look-and-feel, you need more than just a Ribbon. You want a Office theme or style.
Your best bet here is to get a (commercial) component, that does all the heavy lifting for your. There are many Office style components out in the market. 
The most known vendor in this segment is Infragistics. There is also an open source alternative called OpenXava (it's good, but rather different).
Syncfusion is also a well known name, that has (more) affordable, but more Metro styled set of components.

Comment: @wp78de Please do not answer off topic questions, and do not answer questions via comments.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [SyncFusion](http://syncfusion.com) they provide community license for free.

Also you may like this library: [Modern UI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) if your application is really simple (available via NuGet also).

Nice vector icons are here : [enter link description here](http://modernuiicons.com/)  (available via NuGet also).

Answer (score -1):

Edraw Max uses qtitanribbon.dll, coded in c++. But you can use it also in other programming languages.

Comment: Please do not answer off topic questions.